# Issues With ItemsContainerGenerator and Recycling

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

It seems I cannot figure out this problem on the internet well so I am asking you guys. I would like to know what is the difference between using ItemsContainerGenerator inside it's custom Panel's measure method with and without calling the Recycle on containers.

My guess is that generator creates new containers and connects them to data items once the method GenerateNext is called but does generator always connects item to their containers in GenerateNext method? With always connecting containers to items I mean, does it links containers that have been already generated/realized over again to their data items?

What will happen if I start recycling containers by calling the recycle() method. Would the generator then still always link containers to items?

I am asking this because the scrolling performance depends usuall on this. If the generator always connects items to containers that would mean it refreshes DataContext/Binding and scrolling would lag little bit. Though if by using recycle method the generator stops refreshing Bindings the scrolling would run pretty smoothly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using the Recycling virtualization mode, containers are reused, so they are nor necessairly connected to their origin data objects. So if your container template contains elements that will rebuild their visual tree on data (or its type or properties) change - they will. To improve performance I can suggest you to create as independent from data change template, as it possible,  minimize visual tree. Also you can modify your ClearContainer method to prevent resetting some global values that are not depending from data: it can be a reference to some big parent control, settings - anything that usually constant but affects visual tree on change.